# most general solution for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am facing some difficulties understanding the difference between a general solution and the most general solution of a 2nd order ODE

for example for homogeneous constant coefficients case with 2 real roots, is $y=C_1 e^{r_1x}+C_2 e^{r_2x}$ a general solution or the most general solution?

and how can I prove that a general solution is the most general one?

Answer (score 1):

There are many kinds of 2nd Order ODEs. Some are (In)homogeneous, some are (Non-)linear. So this question is kind of vague on what you want as a general solution.

Note: *I mostly use $\mathbb{R}$ for constants as i'm not always sure whether i can use $\mathbb{C}$ but generally it should work too. All functions here are of the form $y(x)$.
Every equation here for which i provide solutions is second order here. Inhomogeneous means the same as non-homogeneous.*

**The 'most general' ODE**

$$ y''(x)= F(x,y,y') $$

has no general solutions as non-linear equations may never be solved generally. Some can be solved but there is no general rule for it.

**The Linear Inhomogeneous ODE**((independent) variable coefficient)

$$ (ax^{k}+b)y''+ (cx^{l}+d)y' + (ex^m+g)y = F(x) $$

where $a,b,c,d,e,g \in \mathbb{R} $ and $ k,l,m \in \mathbb{R} $
may or may not have a solution, involves some sort trick to be solved usually and even if there is a solution it's not given like you classically learnt.

When $k=2, l=1, m=2$ and $a=1, b=0, c=1, d=0, e=1, g=-\alpha^2 \hspace{4mm} \alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ and $F(x)=0$
you get the [**Bessel-equation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function)

$$ x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-\alpha)y=0 $$

whose solution cannot be given with elementary functions and you need a special series with the gamma function to calculate specific values of it.

The Bessel functions of the first kind being $J_\alpha$ are defined as such:

$$ J_{\alpha}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!\Gamma(n+\alpha+1}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^{2m+\alpha},$$

where $\Gamma(x)$ is the [Gamma-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

A more 'regular' ODE would be the **(Cauchy-)Euler equation** whose general form is:

$$ a_nx^ny^{(n)} + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}y^{(n-1)} + a_{n-2}x^{n-2}y^{(n-2)} + ... +a_0y=0$$

Here the (n) in the superscript means the n-th order derivative.

The second order version of it let's say is in the form:

$$ ax^2y''+ bxy'+cy=0$$

where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R} $

The general solution for this kind of equation is reached like this:

First substitute $y=x^m,\;\; y'=mx^{m-1},\;\; y''=m(m-1)x^{m-2} $

Then the transformed equation will look like this:

$$ax^2\cdot m(m-1)x^{m-2} + bx\cdot mx^{m-1} + c x^m =0$$

Notice how the x powers fall out and we can factor out $x^m$.

Thus we get: $$x^m[am(m-1)+bm+c]=0 $$

Divide by $x^m$ which can never be $0$ and we arrive to this simple problem:

$$am^2-(a+b)m+c=0$$

Solve for $m$ and plug your results into this: $$y = c_1x^m_1 + c_2x^m_2$$

If there is a resonance($m_1=m_2$) we multiply our results by $\ln(x)$ so they will be linearly independent(take note how this is similar when this happens with a constant coefficient ODE)

$$ y= c_1x^m\ln(x) + c_2x^m $$

If our solutions are of the complex form $ \alpha \pm \beta i$

$$ y=c_1x^\alpha \cos(\beta\ln(x)) + c_2x^\alpha \sin(\beta\ln(x)) $$

If F(x) is not zero then you need to find the particular solution first, you can find more of this at the bottom of this answer.

**Constant Coefficient Linear Homogeneous ODE**

$$ ay''+by'+cy=0 $$

where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{C} $

We transform this into an algebraic problem:

$$ ar^2+br+c=0 $$

Solve it for r, get your results in $\alpha$ and $\beta$

the solution of this is as you wrote:

$$ y= c_1e^{\alpha x}+c_2 e^{~beta x}$$

If there is a resonance($\alpha=\beta$)

$$ y= (c_1+c_2x)e^{\alpha x / 2} $$

If the two roots are of the complex form $\alpha \pm \beta i$

$$ y= e^{\alpha x}(c_1\cos(\beta x)+c_2\sin(\beta x)) $$

**Constant Coefficient Linear Inhomogeneous ODE**

$$ ay''+by'+cy=F(x) $$

When $F(x) \neq 0$, you solve the inhomogeneous term $F(x)$ with [Variation of Parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) or [Method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients) (some schools also teach the [Annihilator Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_method)), then you add this to the homogeneous  general solution thus getting the whole inhomogeneous general solution for that kind of problem.

$$ y_{hom.gen.}+y_{inhom.part.}=y_{inhom.gen.} $$

These are the ones that i had the top off my head. I am not really sure what you could prove about this. Maybe you could (re)formulate your question a bit better.